# Safest way to add/extend partition on linux

Tags: linux, partition, lvm

I have a linux server that is running out of space. There are already 4 primary partitions, which I believe is the max number of partitions. So I am unable to create a new parition as per this article: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006371

How would I extend the current partitions or create partition safely(without data lost)?.

The partitions are LVMs.

Comment: the MBR concept of *primary/logical/extended* partitioning is basically obsolete, and has been for years. you shouldn't have to worry about that. a GPT disk just has *partitions*, and won't sweat many hundreds or thousands depending on the size of the table you write. if it is a problem for you, though, you probably want a new partition table. `gdisk` can do a conversion for you.

Comment: What type of partitions do you have? There hasn't been a limitation to 4 partitions since a decade before Linux even existed — with the MBR partitioning scheme, you can have up to 4 primary partitions but any number of logical partitions (Linux can only access 12 by default though). And with LVM there's no practical limit. Post the output of `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs`.

Comment: PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  VolGroup lvm2 a--   39.51g    0
  /dev/sda3  VolGroup lvm2 a--   10.00g    0
  /dev/sda4  VolGroup lvm2 a--  469.99g    0

  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  VolGroup   3   2   0 wz--n- 519.50g    0

  LV      VG       Attr      LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_root VolGroup -wi-ao--- 515.62g
  lv_swap VolGroup -wi-ao---   3.88g

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to make it easier to see on here..